# If remove duplicate is clicked yes then pd.dataframe drop_duplicates else keep old pd.dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm stuck with this expression: If "deleteDup" is True then execute pd.dataframe drop_duplicates else keep old pd.dataframe?
Here is my code and it didn't work:
`df = df.drop_duplicates() if deleteDup else df = df`
(`deleteDup` is a button that will return True or False.)
error when running this code:

````
 df = df.drop_duplicates() if deleteDup else df = df
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='?```
````

Comment: Unless you have a specific need to cram your code into one line, breaking a statement  over multiple lines will almost always be easier to read, interpret, and debug. `if deleteDup: df=df.drop_duplicates`

Answer (score 0):

In `else` clause you should leave `df` as is, not explicitly assign it to `df`:

`df = df.drop_duplicates() if deleteDup else df`